# Making double and std::vector<double> covariant

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, covariance

I am trying to make a wrapper for "any" data type such that they have common interface called `IValue` so it will be possible to call `get()` on any concrete Value and return the value of concrete data type. In simplest case I just want to be able to call `get()` on `double` and `std::vector<double>`. In my understanding these data types need to be covariant (which it is not at all in my code). The following is my raw imagination of the code:

```
//template<typename T>
class IValue 
{
protected:
    // typedef std::variant<T, std::vector<T>> return_type; <- this was an approach
public:
    IValue() {}

    virtual int size() = 0;

    virtual /*some special type*/ get() = 0;
};


template<typename T>
class Scalar : public IValue<T> {
    T data = NULL;
public:

    Scalar(T new_data) : data(new_data) {}

    T get() { return data; }

    int size()  { return 1; }
};


template<typename T>
class Vector : public IValue<T> 
{
    std::vector<T> data;
public:

    Vector(std::vector<T> new_data) : data(new_data) {}

    std::vector<T> get() { return data; }

    T get_element(int index) { return data[index]; }

    int size()  { return data.size(); }
};
```

I am using c++17 on VS17.

Comment: You can't do this with run time polymorphism because there is no way to make these type covariant.  I suggest looking into CRTP which does compile time polymorphism and allows you to return different types.

Comment: Is `IValue` a `std::span` to 1 or more `double`? (No need of inheritance neither in that case too BTW).

Comment: @Jarod42 Not quite, `IValue` should provide a class with one value of specific type and also some functionality "of having a value" such as looking for rather if it's "set" or in case of vector asking for its size.

Answer (score 1):

You're indeed almost there. `std::variant<T, std::vector<T>>` is indeed the correct return type, and your `get() { return data; }` implementations are also correct. Literally the only big problem is that the return type of all `get` overrides should be `std::variant<T, std::vector<T>>`.

Stylewise, `get` should be `const` and adding `override` helps to improve error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance only applies to pointer/reference of polymorphic types.

so you have to wrap `double`/`vector<double>` in some class:

```
struct IWrapper
{
    virtual ~IWrapper() = default;
};

struct DoubleWrapper : IWrapper
{
    double d = 0.;
};

struct DoubleVecWrapper : IWrapper
{
    std::vector<double> v;
};
```

And then you can have something like:

```
class IValue 
{
public:
    virtual ~IValue() = default

    virtual int size() = 0;
    virtual IWrapper& get() = 0;
};


class Scalar : public IValue {
    DoubleWrapper data;
public:
    explicit Scalar(double d) : data(d) {}

    T& get() override { return data; }
    int size() override { return 1; }
};


class Vector : public IValue
{
    DoubleVecWrapper data;
public:

    Vector(const std::vector<T>& v) : data(v) {}

    DoubleVecWrapper& get() override { return data; }
    int size() override { return data.v.size(); }

    T get_element(int index) { return data[index]; }
};
```

but without meaningful interface, it is mostly useless

```
// No use of Base interface or inheritance, so ok
void foo(Scalar& value)
{
    const auto size = value.size();
    auto& wrapper = value.get(); // auto& is DoubleWrapper&
    wrapper.d = 4.2;
}

// But, with base class, we cannot go really far:
void foo(IValue& value)
{
    const auto size = value.size();
    auto& wrapper = value.get(); // auto& is IWrapper&
    // What to do now? IWrapper can't do anything
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is that I try to create a template mechanism to work perfectly working with any data types, I am looking for one perfect solution witch does not seem to be possible (in terms of usability and elegance) in this case.